# Prove that intersection of nested closed sphere is not empty without $r_{n}\to 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a Banach space E, let $B_{p_n}(z_{n})= \left\{x\in E: ||x-z_{n}||\leq p_{n}\right\}$, $z_{n}\in E$, $p_n\geq 0$, $n=1,2,...$ be a sequence of closed balls in $E$ such that $B_{p_1}(z_{1})\supseteq B_{p_2}(z_{2})\supseteq B_{p_3}(z_{3})\supseteq...$. Prove that $\cap_{n} B_{p_n}(z_n)\neq \emptyset$. (Hint: if a ball $B_{\delta}(x)$ lies in a ball $B_{p}(z)$, then $\delta\leq p$ and $||x-z||\leq p-\delta$. It's not assumed that $p_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

My current thought, after looking at the proof of nested sphere theorem, is trying to build a Cauchy sequence {x_n} such that $||x_n-x_{n_1}||\leq p_n-p_{n_1}$, $||x_n - x_{n_2}||\leq p_n-p_{n-1}-p_{n-2},$ and so on... (since we don't have $p_n \to 0$, which is the key point in the original proof). Or maybe we can have a way to construct the nested closed spheres using the hint, such that the RHS will be $p-p_{n}$, $p-2p_{n}$, and so on.. But I haven't been able to get an explicit construction. Can someone please help me with a detailed construction?

Comment: From the hint, you know that the sequence of radii is monotonic, hence convergent. Let $\rho = \lim \rho_n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer that's a good observation, but can you show a construction of ${x_{n}}$ such that ${x_{n}}$ is Cauchy (or stronger, convergent)? $rho= lim \rho_{n} \neq 0$, so how do we proceed further?

Comment: What does the hint then imply about the sequence of the centres of the balls?

Comment: implies they converge to some point x such that $||x-z_{n}||\leq \delta- p_{n}$? But I thought what we need is the sequence ${p_n-p_{n+1}}$ converges, but such sequence is not guaranteed to be monotonic?

Comment: Well, try proving the sequence of centres is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for your patience, and apologize for my stupidity. Please help check my proof for $\left\{z_n\right\}$ is Cauchy, and the rest: since $\left\{p_n\right\}$ is a convergent sequence, $p_n$ is also Cauchy. This implies $\exists N$ such that for any $\epsilon >0$, $|p_n-p_m|< \epsilon$ for $m,n\geq N$. Since $|p_n-p_m|\geq ||x_n-x_m||$ (from the hint), we get $\left\{x_n\right\}$ is also Cauchy. Thus $\left\{x_n\right\}$ converges to a point $x$ in $E$ (since E is complete). The point $x$ must be in each closed ball $B_{p_n}(z_n)$ for $n\geq N$. Is this correct?

Comment: I meant, is the whole proof correct, since the sentence before the last showed that the intersection of $B_{p_n}(z_n)$ is non-empty.

Comment: You need - if you want to present the proof to others, it's not necessarily necessary if you just want a sketch to remind you of how the proof goes - to add more details, but the outline is correct. Why must the limit be in each closed ball?

Comment: @DanielFischer because the point $x$ is the limit point of some sequences $x_{n_k}$ lie in each closed ball (in fact, $x_{n}$ is the center of a closed ball, as well as $x_{m}$, so there must exist such subsequence). This is an argument used in proving the Nested Sphere theorem's forward direction: "R is complete => all nested sequence of closed spheres with $r_n\to 0$ has non-empty intersection"

Comment: I meant that if you present the proof you need to say why that is. Since the balls are nested, $x_m \in B_{\rho_n}(x_n)$ for all $m \geqslant n$, so $x = \lim_{m\to\infty} x_m \in B_{\rho_n}(x_n)$.